# How to get current device lattide and longitude of iphone device and update on server db weather device is running or not

Tags: php, iphone, cron

1. My requirement is like that i have to send push notification when
   user comes in a particular radius of latitude and longitude .

   So i need to update current latitude and longitude of device  on
   server database for matching (weather device is running or not).

   Please give me an idea , solution  so i can fulfill my requirement
   successfully.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite the ask to request someone does this for you.

There are a few tasks you need to complete:

1. Within the app itself, grab the current latitude and longitude.
2. Then you need an API to pass the data back to the database.
3. You'll need a database to store this data in.
4. Do whatever you want to do with the data (maybe a push?).

So investigate how to go about each of those and it'll get you started...

Comment: 1.Within the app itself, grab the current latitude and longitude. How this is possible when app in ideal / kill mode?